# Caffe installation, linking issue

Tags: linux, linker, caffe, ubuntu-16.04, dynamic-linking

I have the following issue encoutering during caffe installation:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs

I built opencv3.2, but I believe I have an issue with linking the `cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` library. I tried adding it to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it still fails with the same error.

Shall I make a link to the `cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` in the LD path? if yes, which path exactly shall I make the link in it.

Here is the last few lines of the output (the error msg):

```
CXX examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.cpp
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:572: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741072/unable-to-install-caffe/43088610

Comment: I did find nothing of use in that solution, I also do not want to try `conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0` as I already compiled and build by hand the opencv3.2 and willing to know which step I miss now. It am thinking it is a linking issue

Comment: It can't find the way to reach libopencv_imgcodecs.so, check where it is located & add same path in LIBRARY_DIRS of Makefile.config

Comment: I found that in `/home/<username>/anaconda3/envs/<env-name>/lib` and I believe you are right! it fixed the erorrs, now I better solve the other erros :D Thanks!
Please add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't find the way to reach libopencv_imgcodecs.so, check where it is located & add same path in LIBRARY_DIRS of Makefile.config

Open your Makefile.config file, you'll find the following lines:

```
  # Whatever else you find you need goes here.
    INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include
    LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib
```

If you've found the location, for example /home/username/anaconda3/envs/env-name/lib, then add it to LIBRARY_DIRS.

```
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /home/<username>/anaconda3/envs/<env-name>/lib
```

Comment: I found the reason why it failed, 
in `PYTHON_LIB := $(ANACONDA_HOME)/lib`
I changed `ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda3/`
 to `ANACONDA_HOME := $(HOME)/anaconda3/envs/<env-name>/` and adjusting the PYTHON_INCLUDE path correspondly fixed my issue :)

Comment: If anyone came across this issue and cannot locate the library, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12335952/871418. Also you can look for it in other ways like ctrl + F in some suspected directories